# Movesense calibration

Tags: movesense

is it possible to calibrate acc and gyro on Movesense device via [API](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/misc/calibration.yaml) ?
I would like to compensate constant bias on acc and gyro, but I'm not sure how to use the API.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no "built-in" bias calibration in the framework/API. The reasoning is that it would take memory from everybody (not all apps need it) while not working for all the use cases. Bias-removal is also a feature with quite straight forward implementation:

- Make sure that sensor is still for the duration of the bias calibration. The duration depends on application, samplerate and accuracy required (this very application specific).
- Measure Acc + Gyro (i.e. */Meas/IMU6* ) with the samplerate that you normally use
- run sanity check on the acc & gyro data you receive for example stdev of each axis (no movement nor rotation!)
- calculate average of each axis => This is the bias correction that you need to subtract from the actual measurements before you do anything else with them.

Since both average and stdev can be calculated incrementally there is no need to reserve RAM-buffers for the calibration.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*